# Grabbing the output of MAPLE via Python

Tags: python, subprocess, pexpect, maple

How would I use the subprocess module in Python to start a command line instance of MAPLE to feed and return output to the main code? For example I'd like:

```
X = '1+1;'
print MAPLE(X)
```

To return the value of "2".

The best I've seen is a SAGE wrapper around the MAPLE commands, but I'd like to not install and use the overhead of SAGE for my purposes.

Comment: Could you describe the way the Maple command line interface works? Is it a standard read-evaluate-print loop like Python, or is there a `-c "command"` switch you can use to have it immediately evaluate the results of a command?

Comment: If it was the process would be simple, MAPLE does have a -c "command" switch but the process doesn't exit (it runs an interactive mode). Ideally I'd like to leave the pipe open - that is compute in MAPLE, then python then back to MAPLE again without starting MAPLE each time due to the long loading when it starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the tip from Alex Martelli (thank you!), I've came up with an explicit answer to my question. Posting here in hopes that others may find useful:

```
import pexpect
MW = "/usr/local/maple12/bin/maple -tu"
X = '1+1;'
child = pexpect.spawn(MW)
child.expect('#--')
child.sendline(X)
child.expect('#--')
out = child.before
out = out[out.find(';')+1:].strip()
out = ''.join(out.split('\r\n'))
print out
```

The parsing of the output is needed as MAPLE deems it necessary to break up long outputs onto many lines. This approach has the advantage of keeping a connection open to MAPLE for future computation.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to drive a subprocess "interactively" more often than not runs into issues with the subprocess doing some buffering, which blocks things.

That's why for such purposes I suggest instead using [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) (everywhere but Windows: [wexpect](http://code.google.com/p/wexpect/downloads/list) on Windows), which is designed exactly for this purpose -- letting your program simulate (from the subprocess's viewpoint) a human user typing input/commands and looking at results at a terminal/console.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to do interactive IO with a command line program. I used something similar to build a spell checker based on the `ispell` command line utility:

```
f = popen2.Popen3("ispell -a")
f.fromchild.readline() #skip the credit line

for word in words:
    f.tochild.write(word+'\n') #send a word to ispell
    f.tochild.flush()

    line = f.fromchild.readline() #get the result line
    f.fromchild.readline() #skip the empty line after the result

    #do something useful with the output:
    status = parse_status(line)
    suggestions = parse_suggestions(line)
    #etc..
```

The only problem with this is that it's very brittle and a trial-and-error process to make sure you're not sending any bad input and handling all the different output the program could produce.