# Open command prompt in the background

Tags: python

Need help, so what I am trying to do is :-

I wanna setup a python program, that will open command prompt in background, and I will be able to give commands as input to python program, it will then forward that commands to command prompt and gives me output, I want this connection to be established for the time I want,

I have been through some python codes, what happens in them is, when I enter command, it displays me results at once then it exits, I don't want that instance of command prompt to exit till I want, so I can make changes, change directories, etc.

I have tried, but no such result :( .

So if any ideas do help me out.

Thnx folks.

Comment: Don't just say "i have tried", tell us _what_ you've tried, and what the result is. Meanwhile: The way to open a command prompt, or any other program, is the `subprocess` module. If you want to control input and output instead of having it just mix in with your own input and output, the key is `subprocess.PIPE`. The way to do something in the background is the `threading` module. That should be all you need here. Just show us where you got stuck.

Comment: ohk sure dude, 
well basic logic is, 
i want to create a python program, then will connects or binds with command prompt, so i can give commands to it, subprocess works, but command prompt exits after entering one command or so, i want that same instance to work for the time i want.

i am planning for something like following 

import subprocess 

commands prompts starts 

while 1:
     a = enter commands 
     process.stdin.write(a+"\n")
     communicate()
if a == ' ':
     exit the command prompt

Thanks

Comment: Yes, `communicate` just sends one hunk of input and gets back one hunk out output. You need to actually use read and write the `PIPE`s yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with `subprocess`, here's what you do:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['sh'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Now, every time you want to send a command, you have to `p.stdin.write()` the command. And you have to `p.stdout.read()` the result.

But those are blocking calls. So, what you probably want is:

- A reader thread that loops on `p.stdout.read()` and posts to a `queue.Queue`
- A writer thread that loops on a different `queue.Queue` and does `p.stdin.write()`.
- A main thread that deals with user input and output via the queues.
- Possibly a fourth thread to `wait` on the `Popen` object itself.

This isn't easy, but the [source code to `communicate`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/subprocess.py#l1181) will show you how to do it. (Make sure to read the 3.2 or later version, because earlier versions didn't actually do it right.)

If you want something simpler, use a higher-level library like `pexpect` or any of the dozen or so shell wrappers on PyPI.

Comment: Thnx dude , helpful, i ll check pexpect too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I remember. The way to keep the subprocess shell open is to keep the `stdin PIPE` open

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(['whatever'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,shell=True)
process.stdin.write('Hello\n')
print repr(process.stdout.readline()) 
process.stdin.write('World\n')
print repr(process.stdout.readline()) 

#close
process.stdin.close()
process.wait()
```

But it isn't recomended and it is unreliable. Use [`pexpect`](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) (non-Windows) and for windows use [`winpexpect`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/winpexpect/1.4).

In reference to this thread, [Keeping a pipe to a process open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346650/keeping-a-pipe-to-a-process-open)

Take a look at this question as well, [Using module 'subprocess' with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/subprocess-with-timeout)

Also take a look at this code from activestate, http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576911-keep-a-process-up-and-running/

Comment: This only works if you only need a single line of response (or, alternatively, know exactly how many lines you should need) from `process.stdout`. Otherwise, you have to just keep calling `read` until you block… at which point you're blocked, and your whole program is stuck. You can't work around this with `select` in a portable way, so the only real option is threads. Which is why, in Python 3.2+, `communicate` uses threads.

Comment: Thnx buddy for your help

Comment: In particular, if `'whatever'` is `'sh'` or `'cmd'`, and what's you're writing to it is arbitrary commands, there's no way you can possibly know how much to read in response.