# Decomposing integral into elliptic integrals

Tags: python, sympy

This integral cannot be evaluated.

```
>>> from sympy import integrate, sin, cos,sqrt, Symbol
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> integrate(1/sqrt(1+sin(x)**2),x)
Integral(1/sqrt(sin(x)**2 + 1), x)
```

Does sympy not support decomposing integrals into elliptic integrals as mathematica, wolfram alpha, or maple do?  ([wolfram answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt%281%2Bsin%28x%29%2a%2a2%29))

I tried looking in the sympy buglist under the integration label, but nothing jumped out at me (there was something on recognizing elliptic integrals, but the bug description wasn't clear to me).

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I am aware they are not supported. Currently, sympy uses the Risch (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) algorithm as well as handling a some, but not all, non-elemtary cases, e.g. it handles integrals of gaussians. See http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/integrals/integrals.html

Comment: @Lucas SymPy also has a very powerful algorithm that uses Meijer G-functions to evaluate integrals in terms of special functions.

Comment: @asmeurer Not knowing things like that is why I thought I'd leave it to you to give a more detailed answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy's integrators are always improving, but there are still several classes of integrals that they cannot do yet.  This is apparently one of them. Feel free to open new issues in the bug tracker for things like this. It's definitely something that we *want* to be able to do.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I'll open an issue.  I ended up finding a solution to my symbolic needs using this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053231/grabbing-the-output-of-maple-via-python

Comment: We discussed the things that need to be done for this to work at http://colabti.org/irclogger/irclogger_log/sympy?date=2013-06-09#l151. Already it lead to a [pull request](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/2165) to make things work with complete elliptic integrals.

Comment: I noticed recently that the pull request was completed.  Does having the functions in the Meijer-G table mean that integrals that can be expressed as complete elliptic ints are now possible?  I tried the latest copy from github on a definite integral, but no luck.

Comment: No, unfortunately, that was only for complete elliptic integrals, but your integral needs incomplete ones, which are not as easy to do with the Meijer G-function (according to the author of that pull request). See the IRC log I linked to above.

Comment: Oh, no no, I get that. I did try it on something that is expressible in terms of complete integrals (particularly, if you integrate the above from 0 to Pi: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt%281%2Bsin%28x%29**2%29+from+0+to+Pi )

Comment: Or does the integral need to fulfill this requirement in its indefinite form?

Comment: @Grant I don't know the answer to your question. Can you ask at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/2165 ?

Comment: I think I answered my own question actually.  According to the sympy docs, meijer-G integration only applies in the definite case to [0,inf]. So yes, the definite version of the integral above is not possible either.

Comment: Sure, but it can also apply to the indefinite case, and I think there might be some cases in the code where it changes to `0, oo` by a change of variable.

Comment: Obviously not for this one, but I'm just saying that sometimes it does work.

Comment: OK, the correct answer is at https://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=2063#c9. That pull request only handles integrands that contain K(z) or E(z), not those that produce them.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. Should I be tuned into this issue for future updates? --> https://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=1393

Comment: Sure. Also feel free to open an issue for just this particular integral (I don't think we have one yet).